# React-Google-Maps showed grey area on container div resize

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I am working on a React app using React-Google-Maps package. My current page has a left sidebar and it's collapsible. When I clicked a button to make the left sidebar collapsed, the google maps inside main div did not fit its container.

I did try this but nothing happened:

```js
google.maps.event.trigger( 
  this.__map.context['__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED'], 
  'resize'
)
```

Comment: how about you rerender the google map component when the sidebar collapsed

Comment: @Muhaimin: I tried `this.forceUpdate()` but the grey area is still there.

Comment: What i mean is when sidebar collapsed, how about you trigger the map component to rerender based on the state of sidebar

Answer (score 1):

The code that you provided works, *however*, the resize triggers with the currently visible div when it's called. This assumes that your sidebar has a bit of an animation associated with it, and that code is being called at the same the sidebar is being closed. SO, just add a timeout function before triggering the resize.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    google.maps.event.trigger(
        this.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED,
        'resize'
    )
}, 500) // modify as you see fit
```

```